# Executing methods at random time intervals

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, sdk

What is the best way of repeatedly executing a method at random time intervals, so for example the code in the method is run at 1s, 3s, 7s, 10s, 11s, 13s, 19s, 22s, etc,. for an infinite amount of time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would set a timer and on each time through check against a random number and if that random number hits then call the function:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithInterval: 1.0 target:self selector:@selector(targetMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];
```

and in the targetMethod

```
if(arc4random() % 10 == 1)
{
   //call your function
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int randomInt = (arc4random() % 100) + 1;
NSTimer *yourTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:randomInt target:self selector:@selector(timedMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

the code above will fire at random time interval within 1s to 100s

Answer (score 1):

You can define time as per need or as you want, calculate it and use-

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:yourTime target:self selector:@selector(mainloop) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
-(void) executeMethod
{
    NSLog(@"Method being executed");
}

-(void) callingRandomTimedMethod
{
    for (int i = 1; i > 0; i=i+2) {
        [self executeMethod];
        sleep(i);
    }
}
```

This gives output like (check the time gap):

```
> 2012-06-27 11:59:31.757 FirstApp[804:fb03] Method being executed
> 2012-06-27 11:59:32.760 FirstApp[804:fb03] Method being executed
> 2012-06-27 11:59:35.762 FirstApp[804:fb03] Method being executed
> 2012-06-27 11:59:40.765 FirstApp[804:fb03] Method being executed
> 2012-06-27 11:59:47.767 FirstApp[804:fb03] Method being executed
> 2012-06-27 11:59:56.769 FirstApp[804:fb03] Method being executed
```

Comment: the code will hang completely while sleep.. not so good to use this.